# upload, download multiple binary files

Tags: download, upload, jhipster

Upon clicking a button, I want to get many files from user, upload them to server, and store them in many records with blob field.

Similarly, clicking a button would download files into user specified local folder.

Any material or direction to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have a single blob field.  I want to store each file in different record.  As I wont know the number of files uploaded before-hand, I wont be able to define many blob in the same record.

Comment: Then you should update your question. as it missing crucial details. Although you seem to focus on client side, I wonder how you are going to design your REST resource. Your are quite far from JHipster approach so I guess you should probably split up your question in 2 or 3 (client, rest, upload versus download) and tag it accordingly to reach wider audience because I doubt JHipster community will give you enough help and you need to show what you have tried.